# Using git to update workspace to the latest revision without commit local changes

Tags: git, migration

Recently I migrated to git from SVN, just wondering how can I update my workspace to the latest revision with out commit local changes!

Answer (score 0):

Have you by chance heard of [stash](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing)? 
This essentially creates a patch that git manages, return rolls back changes to clean state. Update your WC then pop there stash

Comment: No I haven't! stash is very interesting, thank you. does it merge the latest version with local changes? I want to update my workspace with latest version

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with the git+svn workflow, but I would surmise that you would be able to perform normal WC updates then re-apply the stash

Comment: git is too much complicated to simple routine tasks :(